# Jquery autocomplete not showing selected item in search box when scrolling through the list

Tags: jquery-ui

When scrolling through the list of options, the values being highlighted are not being displayed in the search box. I am using the jquery-ui version 1.10.3.
It is working correctly when i select them through keyboard.

Code:

```
_createAutocomplete: function () {
                var selected = this.element.children(":selected"),
             selectedvalue = selected.text()
                             ? selected.text() : "";

                this.input = $("<input>")
                          .appendTo(this.wrapper)
                          .val(selectedvalue)
                          .attr("title", "")
                          .addClass("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left")
                          .autocomplete({
                              minLength: 4,
                              source: $.proxy(this, "_source")
                          })
                          .tooltip({
                              tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
                          });

                this._on(this.input, {
                    autocompleteselect: function (event, orgselect) {
                        var newvar = this.input.val();
                        $("#control option").filter(function () {
                            return this.value == newvar;
                        }).attr('selected', true);
                        this.input.val($("#control option:selected").text());
                    },
                    autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
                });
```

Comment: please post your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery-ui `focus` function to highlight the value in the input box :

```
$( "#demo" ).autocomplete({
  source: texts,
  focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#demo" ).val( ui.item.label );
    return false;
  }
  });
```